# (R) Function using merge() - put by.x and by.y as parameters -> error message

Tags: r, function, parameters, merge, output

I am trying to create a function that at the end would map data. So in the function, I merge the `outputfile` and `datafile` loaded by the function user. It works when the `by.x` and `by.y` are the column names of the files I load, like this:

```
OA.Blabla<- merge(outputfile, datafile, by.x="location", by.y="city")
```

but when I try putting them as parameters like this:

```
function1<-function(data, outputfile, datafile, x, y)
....
OA.Blabla<- merge(outputfile, datafile, by.x="x", by.y="y")
....
```

It gives an error message: `#"Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"`

How can I fix this? I really need them to be as parameters because otherwise the data I load need to be modified before the function for the columns to be renamed `x` and `y`...

Answer (score 1):

If what you have posted is correct you have not used your arguments x and y correctly in the call to *merge* - you have enclosed them in double quotes, treated in the call to merge as meaning you want to merge on fields named "x" and "y", which don't exist in your table. To pass the argument *values* to the merge function remove the double quotes:

```
function1 <-function(data, outputfile, datafile, x, y) .... 
OA.Blabla <- merge(outputfile, datafile, by.x = x, by.y = y)
```